# How to hide and show the table row with if else statement for android

Tags: android

How to hide the table

**Example:**

**if tel != null then** 
   show table row
**else**
   hide table row
**end if**

```
<TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow9"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTelH"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="15"
                android:text="Tel : "
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/apps_title">

            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTelD"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="35"
                android:ems="15"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/apps_title">

            </TextView>

        </TableRow>
```

I want to hide if empty data how to do it... please 
I'm new doing android ...

Comment: share your java code

Comment: Very useful question. @ShubhamRatawa has given an intelligent answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
TableRow tableRow9 = findViewById(R.id.tableRow9);
```

and then

```
if(tel != null)
    tableRow9.setVisibility(View. VISIBLE);
else
    tableRow9.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: if (sTel == "-") {
                tvTelH= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTelH);
                tvTelH.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                tvTelD= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTelD);
                tvAdd1D.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else{
                tvTelD = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTelD);
                tvTelD.setText(sTel);
            }